# Find values greater than zero in a table and list in another table by sequence (excel macro )

Tags: excel, vba, loops, automation

i need help with excel macro vba i am not experienced to do so here what i want
i need a code to extract values from table which are changed due to formulas used
these values should be > 0
I want to pull these values in sequence to another table  in same sheet
assume these values are 5 values and I have only 3 rows in the table I want to add rows to be the same member of the values shown in other table automatically  with serial
range of first table is (E23:P33)
and add to table column from (D23)  and add row automatically till last value in sequence of due date

I wish I explained in the right way
here is pic of two tables
1 - table wish should find values which are greater than 0
[1st table due](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUdGm.png)

2 - table which values are sorted in sequence of due date in the installments due column and add row for values if the number of rows is short
[installments summery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmCDk.png)

i want to pull non zero values from this table
this is made to automation as summery rather than this whole table

i tired out formulas but cannot add rows automatically and there will be blank cells of values that equal to ZERO so the right way is to use vba code

Comment: `SORT` and `FILTER` should probably do what you want. But your second table is blank so we don't know what you want the result to be. It would be better if you filled in the second table with the result you want.

Comment: i want to add the values in table 1 > 0 to the second table a installments due column with out blank cells so i think sort and filter will not work

Comment: The way you have described it, filter will work. That's what filter does. It lets you filter out blank or 0 cells. But again, if you show us the result you want, it will be easier to answer.

Comment: i have edited the post images to the result i want to have
it is like a summery for the table

Answer (score 0):

The data is currently pivoted by month, and you want it arranged in tabular form instead. The easiest way to do this is with the power query unpivot function. Someone may offer an alternate suggestion in VBA.

Your question is still incomplete - you have Type and Due Date in your second table, but they aren't in your first table. Here is some similar sample data.

To transform the blue table into the green table, do the following:

Select your data, and on the Data tab click Get Data From Table/Range. Power Query will open.

In Power Query, Select the month columns. Right click > Unpivot Columns. On the Add Column tab, click Index Column > From 1. On the Home tab click Close & Load.

[image]

Comment: i didn't work for me
i think it needs a macro to be dynamic and automated every time i use this sheet

Comment: If you are going to change the requirements every time someone presents a solution, you will never find one that works for you. Also if you are going to assume you need a macro for no apparent reason, you will miss out on solutions that are more appropriate. To refresh the data in this solution, you just click "Refresh".

Comment: I want solution which is more efficient for me and also for other users if i am not bwing there if i used another way and worked may someone make any edits which make the results not right and i think macro is hidden from being edited by mistake